# Delete or Edit Custom Number Format in Style - MS Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

So I created a new style that inserts a custom number format. After working with it a bit, I needed to edit the number format it but I couldn't figure out how. So I "Define New Number Format" again. Now I need to edit it yet again.

Select Style and right-click -> Modify -> Format -> Numbering... -> Define New Number Format

The problem is that the first never-to-be-used-again number format is still listed in the Numbering Library. I suspect when I Define another New Number Format the current number format will also reside in the Numbering Library in perpetuity. So my Numbering Library is getting clogged with completely useless numbering formats and they are shown as the top suggestions.

Is there a way to delete or edit custom number formats in the Numbering Library?

Comment: If it is in your library: **Right-click > Remove**, if it is just under recent, it will vanish eventually.

Comment: I see. I can't do that from the Styles modification route, but if I access the Numbering Library from Home -> Paragraph section on the ribbon -> Numbering Library, I can. Thank you.